# Unknown build error, 'An item with the same key has already been added.'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Well, I have some static website files that are required to be added to my project's Resources, so i normally selected build action "Resource" but for some reason whenever i rebuild the solution i get this strange error. After fiddling around for couple of hours i noticed that somehow visual studio doesn't include file extensions when naming a resource so i narrowed down the conflict to be in the `fonts` folder.

[image: [1]]]

Questions

- Is this a bug in VS 2017 ?, if not is there a way to actually solve
  this ?

Notes

- If i normally `Build` the solution it succeeds, however if i
  `Rebuild` that's when the error occurs.

Comment: have you tried cleaning it first before rebuilding?

Comment: @Kokombads yeah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if there is an item in your project file being referenced twice. In question [error RG1000: Unknown build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446037/error-rg1000-unknown-build-error) this has happened after a code merge.

After removing that duplicate reference, clean the project and manually delete `obj` and `bin` folder - just to be sure.

Comment: The compiler should give a warning that specifies which item was duplicated.

Comment: I had to up the build verbosity in order to figure it out. In VS 2022, Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Build and Run/MSBuild project build output verbosity: change to Verbose. In my case, my csproj file explicitly included a resource `<Page Include="Themes\Generic.xaml" />` and later included that same resource again `<Page Include="*\*.xaml" />`